# Can I specify the type of the class template when inherits it into a child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-template

Say, I have a parent class template. And want to build several child class upon it. Each child class are typename specific. So can I specify the typename they use when inherit their parent class template?

example of the class definition:

```
 template <class tName1, class tName2>
 class parent
 {
     tName1 a;
     tName2 b;
     ...
 }

 class child: public parent<int, float>
 {
     ...
 }
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: While that doesn't necessarily suffice in C++, a first try (especially with templates) would be to see if it compiles and behaves the way it is supposed.

Comment: I kind of more into understanding why it works so before trying when programming in C++... For You never know when a misunderstood concept will cause unexpected result. And when it happens, it's very difficult to debug that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can do it. It seems like each time I call a template in C++, I have to specify its type or make it into another template. In this case it's specifying its type.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.